# Performance concerns about monitor incoming email for multiple accounts on the server

Tags: performance, email, architecture, monitoring, daemon

I want to write a Server side script / daemon which would monitor multiple email accounts (might become quite a big number) and then send push notifications . My conceptual idea till now is: have a database with accounts and passwords. Iterate through that, check if any new messages are there and then react on that by doing smth with an email and sending push notification to the mobile device of the Client. My biggest concern is perfomance. Looping through thousands accounts doesnt seem right to me , but I cant come up with better solution. Registering an Observer for each account doesnt sound any better..
Any ideas? Im open to any languages (Scripting or programming). Not asking for code, just trying to wrap my head around the concept. 
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think registering an Observer is no better than looping through all accounts on schedule?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get notification before. Well, there could be a loot of accounts and registering an observer for each sounds a lot.. what is important to me is that accounts don't wait too long - "real time" behavior kinda. And when each observer starts doing smith one by one - how is it different? Unless I use multi-threading its all the same. But with multi-threads I would probably go with answer from santimviejo. Open to suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by blocks. Going one by one through all your database entries may take a long time if we are talking of thousands of accounts, maybe you could divide it on several scripts or script executions, taking, lets say, blocks of 100 accounts. So you would have an environment like this: script/thread 1 checking accounts from 1 to 100, script/thread 2 checking accounts from 101 to 200...
This could be done with threads on the same script/program, by using different scrips, or by using a "wrapper" to call the script many times as needed, depending on the amount of entries/blocks. You may need to keep an eye on you server resources, but performance of the checks should improve.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Was trying to avoid multi threading, but seems like that's all that is left ... main script starting n/100 or so times. Definitely now speed vs server power..